# How can I get the image of a PictureBox generated with OpenGL?

Tags: forms, opengl, picturebox, bitblt, gdi

I have associated the PictureBox to OpenGL through its handle

```
hDC = GetDC((HWND)picBoxA->Handle.ToInt64());
```

This works perfectly and the graphics are drawn in the `PictureBox`.

The problem is that I've been looking for all day for a way to get the data to be copied to another `PictureBox` or a bitmap, but I can not find the way.

I have tried it in different ways and I think the logic solution should be copy the device context using `BitBlt`, copying from the `HDC`, but this just copies the background color (`PicBoxA->backColor`).

```
    HDC hdcA = GetDC((HWND)picBoxA->Handle.ToInt64());
    HDC hdcB = GetDC((HWND)picBoxB->Handle.ToInt64());
    BitBlt(hdcB, 0, 0, 100, 100, hdcA, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Where are these image data? How can I access them? Is it not possible to capture the inside of the `PictureBox`?

Comment: I will have to do it in raw if there is no other alternative, but since I wanted to use it as a bitmap for quick repainting and I have no c ++ managed experience, I'm already imagining lots of problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903876/display-unmanaged-rgb-data-in-picturebox  I hope there is an easier solution.

Comment: @user2168007: As soon as you use OpenGL with a GPU accelerated context, much of the GDI functions go out of the window, especially if double buffering is used. You can use `PFD_SUPPORT_GDI` in the pixelformatdescriptor used for creating the context, but doing so will usually drop GPU acceleration.

Comment: I've finally assumed that it seems that windows has no idea what the OpenGL context contains, so I've finally used glReadPixels and it serves me. Now I periodically copy the content to a bitmap and associate it with the picturebox image (which is currently null). This way you do not need to repeat the same rendering, you never lose the content, and it is always redrawn correctly by itself. It is a rather slow, but it is only necessary to make the copy from time to time, periodically or in certain circumstances.